# How to extract first letters of dashed separated words in a bash variable?

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, variables

I would like to extract the first letter of dashed separated words value of my bash variable, like this:

`MY_TEXT=this-is-my-custom-text`

I would like to create a second variable like this:

`MY_INITIALS=timct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the shortest method, but it doesn't require any external processes.

```
IFS=- read -a words <<< $MY_TEXT
for word in "${words[@]}"; do MY_INITIALS+=${word:0:1}; done
```

Comment: Awesome. I accepted this as the best answer, because this is a pure bash without starting external processes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -oP`:

```
MY_TEXT='this-is-my-custom-text'
MY_INITIAL=$(grep -oP '(?<=-|^)\w' <<< "$MY_TEXT" | tr -d '\n')

echo "$MY_INITIAL"
timct
```

Or using `awk`:

```
MY_INITIAL=$(awk -v RS='-' '{printf substr($0,1,1)}' <<< "$MY_TEXT")
echo "$MY_INITIAL"
timct
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MY_TEXT=this-is-my-custom-text
MY_INITIALS=$(sed 's_\([^-]\)[^-]\+\(-\?\)_\1\2_g' <<< "$MY_TEXT")
echo "$MY_INITIALS"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
MY_TEXT=this-is-my-custom-text
MY_INITIALS="${MY_TEXT:0:1}$(grep -oP '(?<=[-])\w' <<< $MY_TEXT |tr -d '\n')"
echo $MY_INITIALS
```

Output:

```
timct
```